# SQL duplicated rows

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have the current table

```
  IP     ID
 666     1
 666     1
 667     2
```

I need a query that will display all duplicates therefore displaying

```
  IP     ID
 666     1
 666     1
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT IP, ID, COUNT(*) c FROM Table1 GROUP BY ID HAVING c > 1;
```

and c is constantly 2 and I can't really interpret the output.

The output

```
  IP     ID    c
 666     1     2
 666     1     2
 667     2     2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    select ip,id
    from
    (
     SELECT IP, ID, COUNT(*) FROM Table1 GROUP BY IP,ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )A;
```

Answer (score 0):

IF your data is as simple as shown in the sample data, this should work for you.

```
SELECT IP, ID FROM Table1 GROUP BY IP, ID HAVING COUNT(IP) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ip,id,count(*) as cnt
FROM table_name
GROUP BY ip,id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem with the output?

You want to display the rows, that exist more than once. For your example it gives you the row with IP=666 and ID=1, c is of course 2, because this row exists 2 times. To delete this count from your output, use

```
SELECT IP, ID FROM Table1 GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: when manually checking one row for another by simply ordering the ips, yes its telling me there are 2 of that row but I can't seem to see it in the order

Comment: Could you please share your output you get with us and tell us, what is missing in your opinion?

Comment: edited question.  my opinion is that its producing 2 for each row when they might not exist twice

Comment: Have you tried to group by both columns?

`SELECT IP, ID FROM Table1 GROUP BY IP, ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;`

Comment: this outputs 0 rows. there should be at least 1 duplicate

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I just created a table exact like yours and the output in phpmyadmin is 1 row: IP 666 and ID 1. What DB are you wrking with?

Comment: im using phpmyadmin too

Comment: Is the code in your question a simplified example of your table or is this really all the content it has got? May this be just a bug in copying queries? (Would like to discuss this with you in chat, but I cannot chat yet)